# CouchBase on Windows Azure.

Tags: azure, couchbase

On Couchbase site (http://www.couchbase.com/partners), we have the following text:

"Microsoft is excited to have Couchbase participate in the Windows Azure Technology Adoption Program. With Couchbase Server, which can be configured to behave like memcached or a Couchbase data store, our customers will be able to create highly elastic data infrastructure, a natural fit for the scaling in the cloud. Couchbase Server and Windows Azure will further enable our customers to focus on solving business problems and addressing their needs at web-scale.

– Robert Duffner, Director of Product Management"

But, besides that, I can't find any information about if it is possible to run CouchBase on Windows Azure. Does anyone have any details about that?

Answer (score 1):

With the preview release of Azure VM roles this is now [relatively straightforward](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/16/couchbase-on-azure-a-tour-of-new-windows-azure-features.aspx).

Comment: There is some [documentation on WindowsAzure.com](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/how-to-run-cassandra-with-linux/) which talks about cassandra and couchbase in the same context

Answer (score 0):

I don't there is any real solution available to get and try. Just to check if I can install and run Couchbase on Windows Azure WebRole, I could do it. In a Web Role I was able to download and install CouchBase directly using Startup task however I had little difficulty to use script to configure it. I use the following steps in my batch file to configure the server correctly:

1. Run C:\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_stop.bat
2. Run C:\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_unregister.bat
3. Edit/Update C:\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_register.bat to add Azure VM internal IP address and not use LocaHost
4. Run C:\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_register.bat
5. Run C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\service_start.bat

So for a single node cluster for couchbase server, I could do it however it really needs to be checked and validated for both server and client about how it works with multiple instances etc..

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is a bit old, but for anyone running into this, I can safely say that YES, you can run CouchBase on Windows Azure.

Much as @el_tone alluded to, you can pretty quickly spin up a VM instance (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 x64), download CouchBase (and optionally Sync Gateway), install them via one line commands (sudo dpkg -i [filename]) and then setup your endpoints accordingly (expose ports 8091 for CB Server and 4984 for Sync Gateway).

Answer (score 0):

There is now quite a bit more information about Windows Azure deployment with Couchbase. Try these posts:

- Step by Step: Production Deployment with Couchbase on Windows Azure Virtual Machines: http://blog.couchbase.com/step-step-production-deployment-couchbase-windows-azure-virtual-machines
- Couchbase on Azure Made Easier: Deploy Couchbase Server on Azure from VM Image Depot: http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-azure-made-easier-deploy-couchbase-server-azure-vm-image-depot
- Few Handy Tricks for Getting Couchbase Server on Ubuntu on Azure Right: http://blog.couchbase.com/few-handy-tricks-getting-couchbase-server-ubuntu-azure-right

Thanks

-cihan biyikoglu

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to email Couchbase directly and asked them about it?

Steve Marx might have done something in this space: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure